# Is there a name for people who don't listen and talk a lot

Tags: terminology

Is there a word representing the behavior of people who talk a lot about what they like and use what you say to get back to a topic they want to talk about?

Comment: The question is rather broad. Words like extraversion and narcissism come to mind. If a person is talking about arcane topics that you have no interest in and the person can't read your lack of interest, it could be some form of autism.